# How do I fix my XML code?

Tags: xml, xslt

ok, I have this XSLT code and it works perfectly, there's just one problem inside the for condition.

```
<xsl:template match="/polinomio">
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
    <derivada>
        <xsl:for-each select="termino">
            <xsl:copy>
                <coeficiente>
                    <parentesis>(</parentesis>
                    <xsl:value-of select="coeficiente * grado" />
                </coeficiente>
                <multi>*</multi>
                <xsl:copy-of select="variable"/>  
                <grado>

                    <grado>^</grado>
                    <xsl:value-of select="grado - 1" />
                </grado>
            </xsl:copy>
        <parentesis>)</parentesis>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </derivada>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is the result I get: 
     (6 * x ^1 ) (8 * x ^3 )
but what I need is to have a plus sign between the two parentheses:
(6 * x ^1 )+(8 * x ^3 ) 
any idea how I should do it?

Comment: please post your xml

Comment: The parentheses are redundant. And you should consider the possibility of a negative coefficient.

Answer (score 2):

If I get your problem right, your `for-each`-loop outputs the parenthesis (....) and you would like to have a plus sign between each parentheses. So, I would add the following code between `<parentesis>)</parentesis>` and `</xsl:for-each>`:

```
<xsl:if test="position() lt last()">+</xsl:if>
```

This puts a + to the output, except for the last run of the loop.